# Regex word boundary alternative

Tags: php, regex, word-boundary

I was using the standard `\b` word boundary. However, it doesn't quite deal with the dot (.) character the way I want it to.

So the following regex:

`\b(\w+)\b`

will match `cats` and `dogs` in `cats.dog` if I have a string that says `cats and dogs don't make cats.dogs`.

I need a word boundary alternative that will match a whole word only if:

1. it does not contain the dot(.) character
2. it is encapsulated by at least one space( ) character on each side

Any ideas?!

P.S. I need this for PHP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try using `(?<=\s)` before and `(?=\s)` after in place of the `\b` to ensure that there is a space before and after it, however you might want to also allow for the possibility of being at the start or end of the string with `(?<=\s|^)` and `(?=\s|$)`

This will automatically exclude "words" with a `.` in them, but it would also exclude a word at the end of a sentence since there is no space between it and the full stop.

Comment: Thanks. Any way I could include words at the beginning and end of a sentence as well?! I might not need it, but it might just be good to know.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to match can be done easily with array and string functions.

```
$parts = explode(' ', $str);
$res = array_filter($parts, function($e){
   return $e!=="" && strpos($e,".")===false;
});
```

I recommend this method as **it saves time**. **Otherwise wasting few hours to find a good regex solution is quite unproductive**.

Comment: I need this as part of another regex as a first step of a `preg_replace` function so it won't quite work for what I need to do

Comment: Then its better to ask what you need actually. There might be better solution than regex.